# TabbarController goes up for incoming phone calls

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, uitabbarcontroller, phone-call

I am working on an application and found a weird issue that when I get a phone call. My UITabbarController goes up and remain same after call ends.

I am not getting the reason behind this.

I would appreciate if someone have an answer for this.

[image]

Comment: How do you add tab controller to window.

Comment: I am using a UINavigationController, UITabbarController is it's second controller. I am using storyboard.So UINavigationController is it's initial view controller. Hope this will clear a picture for you.